# Grid format for python output

Tags: python

I'm trying to print strings into a grid.

The following code gives me the output I expect

```
    for i in range(5):
        for i in range(5):
            print("|            "),
```

[image]

But now I want to place text in that same format using a function:

```
    for i in range(5):
        for i in range(5):
            print(getTask(1)),
```

Where getTask() looks like:

```
   def getTask(task_number):
      task = "blank"
         one = "| Ride on \n| someone's\n| shoulders\n|"

         if task_number == 1:
             task = one

      return task
```

But now my output isn't in the grid format

[image]

Comment: The function "print" has the "end" parameter to control if a newline (or anything else) should be printed after the given data.

Comment: Just use https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, that's what I thought but when I run it I get an invalid syntax error:     `print(getTask(1), end=""),
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` . (the carrot is pointing to the =

Comment: @Vishnudev, it looks like this is for predefined data. I'm intending on populating the grid with my tasks in random orders

Comment: Remove the trailing comma

Comment: @MichaelButscher, changed the output a little, but its still printing to a new line with each iteration

Comment: There are also newlines embedded in the string as \n

Comment: Create that generated data and populate it in a nested list. Then use the list in tabulate. @kreed It makes your life easier and you'll get time to explore more important stuff.